# iOS, Appcelerator Titanium and External Accessory Framework

Tags: ios, titanium, external-accessory

I had a look at Appcelerator Titanium and I was wondering if it lets the developer interact with external accessories the way expected with traditional Apple's Objective-C External Accessory Framework.

Have somebody already explored the thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had used appcelerator in past but moved back to cocoa/obj-c. Appcelerator does make implementation faster for javascript developers but to use anything not provided in the appcelerator package, one needs to create their own modules etc which is a headache.

Moreover, the support for appcelerator is good only if you are in the paid support. Community help is available for free but can't help you in complicated issues requiring modules etc.

Also, appcelerator nearly always lags behind cocoa releases in terms of features, stability etc.

If you're working on a large project then my suggestion would be to stick with cocoa. If you're new to cocoa then appcelerator might be an easy path to explore to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several open sourced modules, these [three](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules) are done by the titanium folks and walk you through [how to create your own](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Module+Developer+Guide+for+iOS). I can't find anything about the "External Accessory Framework" already created in a TiModule.

Comment: Thank you. I've already taken a look at Ti's Module Developer Guide, but I'm mainly confused because embracing Ti I'd need to interface with a "Made for iPhone" device, according to Apple external accessories communication guidelines (which are quite peculiar). I still can't figure out how to bridge EAFramework to Ti. Anyways, thank you so much for your hints.